# Response Redirect info through a masterpage

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

Ok so I'm using I have a Login page which response.redirects the textbox's text to a label so that it will show something like Logged in as : [label]

But I'm using a masterpage and buttons to redirect to different pages and is there anyway to continue using the [label] info?

Comment: are you using asp.net web forms or mvc?

Comment: asp.net webforms but i think i got the solution which is responseredirect info into the master page

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by using response.redirect into an masterpage and coded it from there.